# Use Server generated IDs in sequelize node.js

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

i am starting with sequelize right now and wondered how i can improve this:
I need server generated IDs for my app. The server accepts a new nested Object with IDs.
Now i either have to remove the IDs or overwrite them with a server generated ID. Is there a way to let sequelize do this? I know there is ID generation for defaults, but this doesnt apply here

Code: Controller

```
async createShoppingList(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) : Promise<void>{
    try {
        //Remove IDs
        var list = req.body
        list.SHOPPINGLIST_ID = uuidv4()
        list.USER_ID = req.headers.authorization
        list.Ingredients = list.Ingredients.map(i => ({...i, INGREDIENT_ID: uuidv4()}))
        list.Recipes = list.Recipes.map(r => {
            const ing = r.Ingredients.map(i => ({...i, INGREDIENT_ID: uuidv4()}))
            const ins = r.Instructions.map(i => ({...i, INSTRUCTION_ID: uuidv4()}))
            return {...r, RECIPE_ID: uuidv4(), Ingredients: ing, Instructions: ins}
        })
        //Create
        const result = await ShoppingListRepo.createShoppingList(list)
        res.json(result)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        res.status(404).send({error: error})
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
createShoppingList(shoppingList: Partial<ShoppingListInstance>) :Promise<ShoppingListInstance> {
    return ShoppingList.create(shoppingList,{ validate: true, include: [{association: ShoppingListRecipes, include: [{association: RecipeIngredients}]}, {association: ShoppingListIngredients}] })
}
```

Model:

```
//Data Definition
export interface ShoppingListInstance extends Model {
    SHOPPINGLIST_ID: string
    NAME: string

    Recipes: RecipeInstance[]
    Ingredients: IngredientInstance[]
    USER_ID?: string,

    addRecipes: HasManyAddAssociationMixin<RecipeInstance, string>
    setRecipes: HasManySetAssociationsMixin<RecipeInstance, string>
    removeRecipes: HasManyRemoveAssociationsMixin<RecipeInstance, string>

    addIngredients: HasManyAddAssociationMixin<IngredientInstance, string>
    setIngredients: HasManySetAssociationsMixin<IngredientInstance, string>
    removeIngredients: HasManyRemoveAssociationsMixin<IngredientInstance, string>
}
//Database Schema Definition
export const ShoppingList = sequelize.define<ShoppingListInstance>( 
    'ShoppingList', {
        SHOPPINGLIST_ID: {type: DataTypes.UUID, primaryKey: true, defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4},
        NAME: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
    },{
        timestamps: false
    }
)
//Relations Definition
//Recipes
export const ShoppingListRecipes = ShoppingList.hasMany(Recipe, {
    foreignKey: 'SHOPPINGLIST_ID',
    onDelete: 'CASCADE'
})
Recipe.belongsTo(ShoppingList, { foreignKey: 'SHOPPINGLIST_ID' })
//Ingredients
export const ShoppingListIngredients = ShoppingList.hasMany(Ingredient, {
    foreignKey: 'SHOPPINGLIST_ID',
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
})
Ingredient.belongsTo(ShoppingList, { foreignKey: 'SHOPPINGLIST_ID' })
```

Comment: Maybe sequelize hooks can work for you.
https://sequelize.org/master/manual/hooks.html

Comment: I tried that.
Like: ShoppingList.beforeCreate(() => Id = uuidv4())
But this got me the same id for every submember i.e Recipes. I dont know why

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to generate primary key values by PostgreSQL you need:

1. have `uuid_generate_v4()` as a default value for a primary key column in DB
2. indicate `autoIncrement: true` in a primary key field in a model definition:

```js
// there shouldn't be defaultValue here
SHOPPINGLIST_ID: {type: DataTypes.UUID, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true }
```

3. **Do not** set a value for a primary key field value using `uuidv4()` manually
4. Get and use (if needed) a generated value from the returned model instance after calling `create`:

```js
const createdList = await ShoppingList.create(shoppingListOptions)
console.log(createdList.SHOPPINGLIST_ID) // will output generated PK value
```